# Sitecore: adding new tabs to content editor

Tags: sitecore

I'm looking for a way to extend sitecore's content editor so I can have another tab show up when I click on an item on my content tree.

the purpose is to provide a better user experience when editing some specific information. I have seen this done in some of the addons. An example would be the "E-Commerce" module.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're looking for is a custom editor. Here are several blog posts on the topic:

- [Custom Item Editors in Sitecore](http://paulcaponetti.wordpress.com/2009/12/27/custom-item-editors-in-sitecore/)
- [Creating a Item Editor](http://www.newguid.net/sitecore/2009/creating-a-item-editor/)
- [Editor Tabs in Sitecore](http://www.markstiles.net/Blog/2011/02/27/editor-tabs-in-sitecore.aspx)

Comment: This answer has become useless as 2 of the 3 links are not working anymore

Comment: So what you're saying is that one article about it is not sufficient for you? :-)

Comment: It was the third link that was the real answer, and that's one of the non-working ones.