# How to create custom pages in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

We need to create Custom Pages to manage products in Sitecore.

Product Management

- List the existing products
- Edit, Delete or add new product

The Product information will be stored in Sitecore content tree. How we can create forms in Sitecore to enable users to manage the products?

Comment: What you're describing is the basic functionality of Sitecore. However, I suspect you want your custom forms to perform functionality not provided out of the box. If that is the case, can you please amend your question to specify what you want to achieve, that you can't currently do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the point of having a CMS. To accomplish what you mentioned, all you need is a data template describing your product and create items in the content tree using that template. You should consider building  custom Sitecore pages If you need a custom interface such as a maintenance screen for executing some custom task or trigger a job from within content editor.

Comment: Exactly I want to create custom sitecore pages but with its own layout

Comment: I think the link provided by Thomas should give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you require some custom management functionality, you may want to create a Custom Editor: [Sitecore: adding new tabs to content editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736802/sitecore-adding-new-tabs-to-content-editor)